# Check boxes within the select box

Tags: spring

How to render checkbox within the select box.

Can i use like below code:

```
<form:select path="test" items="testlist">

<input type="checkbox name="test"/>
</form:select>
```

Thanks in Advance.
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it would be nice if it were so easy.  No, you can't do this.  A select box must contain option tags, and option tags contain text.  HTML just doesn't support a multi-select box with checkboxes.

That doesn't mean you can't do it.  Typical workarounds involve javascript and jQuery; [here's an example](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/).  Here's [one that doesn't use jquery](http://lab.arc90.com/2007/07/02/multiselect/).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" checked="checked"/>
```

Comment: That's fine,Is it possible to add checkbox with in the select box.